# Save bools from a scene to another in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've trying to make an adventure game which saves different bools in order to get to the next scene. The problem is that one bool is in another scene with makes it null. Is there any advice?

```
public class Farmer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool NextLevel = false;
    public Cow1 cow1;
    public Cow2 cow2;
    public Cow3 cow3;
    public Dialogue dialogue;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (GetComponent<Cow1>().getIsDisplayed() && GetComponent<Cow2>().getIsDisplayed() && GetComponent<Cow3>().getIsDisplayed())
        {
            NextLevel = true;
        }
        if (NextLevel == true)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().startDialogue(dialogue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is quite an easy way to do this, simply give a game object the `DontDestroyOnLoad` property

```
{
    public bool NextLevel = false;
    public Cow1 cow1;
    public Cow2 cow2;
    public Cow3 cow3;
    public Dialogue dialogue;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
         DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (GetComponent<Cow1>().getIsDisplayed() && GetComponent<Cow2>().getIsDisplayed() && GetComponent<Cow3>().getIsDisplayed())
        {
            NextLevel = true;
        }
        if (NextLevel == true)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().startDialogue(dialogue);
        }
    }
}
```

This will make your game object persistent through scene changes

Comment: Keep in mind to make sure you only have one of those. If this script is attached to an object on scene A and you go back and forth between scene A and B, a new one is added each time. So the Start method should check if there is already an instance of this and destroy any new creation. Some kind of singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of multi-scene editing so you have some values and variables carry on between your scenes. You can learn more about this [here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html)